# BIRT scripting trick

Tags: scripting, report, birt

I've a report with a subreport. I would use all data of one column into a loop and then write the result into footer table. How can I do?

Comment: Why not just add the value into the subreport grid?

Comment: You have just repeated what was in the question. So I will repeat my previous comment: Why not just add the value into the subreport grid?

Comment: No Mark, I already have a subreport! Some values of this must be processed through an algorithm, but I would retrieve all and only values of particular column